# Git checkout without committing user interface state file in Xcode project?

Tags: git, bitbucket, gitignore, git-checkout, xcode10

I clone branch from **bitbucket** and make anew branch from it.

When I want to use **checkout** command to move from created-branch to the master-branch or from master-branch to created-branch when there is no editing -There is no need to commit-, It ask me to commit file UserInterfaceState.

I search about this problem and I found that i need to remove file or add it to git ignore, and I found this command:  **" git rm --cached *.xcuserstate "**.

The above command will remove the file. and I can make checkout to another branch.

But the problem is I need to do the above git command every time I need to **checkout** from one branch to another.

Is there any approach that let me avoid do it every time?

In addition I followed this [site](https://www.raywenderlich.com/675-how-to-use-git-source-control-with-xcode-9) to add built in files to **.gitignore** file but nothing change "**Xcode** ask me again to commit the file '**UserInterfaceState**'".

Is there any solution?

Comment: Unfortunately you will have to perform that command on every branch you have the file already tracked, **and then commit that removal**.

Comment: Is there anyway to add it to .gitignore file?
If it added to the file gitignore i think i dont need to recomit it when it will change.

Comment: No, .gitignore stops `git add .` and similar from adding your files but if the file has already been added and is thus tracked, git will track changes to it and not use `.gitignore` for that file.

Answer (score 0):

When .gitignore file is not working (adding something into .gitignore file or removing something from .gitignore file), you can inspect the following pointers:

- Check for the global gitignore file which sometimes may influence your gitignore.
- Even if you haven't tracked the files so far, git seems to be able to "know" about them even after you add them to .gitignore. Run below command from root of your git repo.

  git rm -r --cached .
  git add .
  git commit -m "fixed untracked files"